# Is UIPATH supports mainframe attachmate emulator?

Tags: uipath

1. By reading blog UIpath is free. Is it free trial or complete free version
2. Will it support attachmate emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Free as in free beer? Depends. Are you an using it as an individual
   or as a legal entity, which is not an enterprise? Then yes. Look up
   all the details here, a blog might not be the most credible source:
   https://www.uipath.com/community-license-agreement
2. Yes, check https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/automating-terminals-and-mainframes

Both questions could have been answered with a simple Google search, though.